# What are the types that pandas.read_csv might infer?

Tags: pandas

If not given a `dtype` parameter [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table) infers the data types of columns in the CSV file. But is there a comprehensive list of the types that pandas might use, so I can handle each of them in my code?

Comment: see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766905/all-pandas-data-types

Comment: Thanks @Jeff looks like it's pretty much a dup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All Pandas Data Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766905/all-pandas-data-types)