# All Pandas Data Types

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a function that will subset a pandas dataframe based on the data type; essentially I am trying to split on numerical and non-numerical columns.

I have gotten as far as:

```
data.dtypes
```

This returns the types of each column, however I cannot find a list of all possible types.  Currently it seems to me that all non-numerical columns are type 'object', is this the case?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas uses `datetime64`, `timedelta64`, `int64`, `float64`, `bool` and `object` (this includes strings and any other custom objects). You can use other types such as `float32`, and pandas will try to maintain it, but some operations will implicitly cast to e.g., `float64`.

Comment: Thanks this helped me out, although I kind of wish I had some sort of authoritative link to the official pandas docs or something to back it up. For now I'm trusting this answer!